# How to print two coordinates from class?

Tags: c++, class

I have been trying to print the points like `The position of the point is (1,2)` from using class, but I can't figure out a way to do it. I simply can't find a way to return two numbers like that, but the problem requires solution that way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyPoint{
    public:
        int x,y,radius;
        MyPoint()
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        MyPoint(int x1,int y1)
        {
            x=x1;
            y=y1;
        }
        int point_display()
        {
            char st=(x,y);
            return st;
        }
        int getAdd()
        {
            return x+y;
        }
};
int main()
{
    MyPoint mypoint;
    cin>>mypoint.x>>mypoint.y;
    cout<<"The position of the point is "<<mypoint.point_display()<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum of the coordinates is "<<mypoint.getAdd()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed to use `std::string` and `std::stringstream`?

Comment: `char st=(x,y);` probably doesn't do what you expect. What *do* you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `point_display` could return a string composed of the 2 values:

```
std::string point_display()
{
  return std::string{"("} + std::to_string(x)
         + "," + std::to_string(x) + ")";
}
```

Alternatively, as your question asks about returning 2 values, the function could return a pair:

```
std::pair<int,int> point_display ()
{
  return {x,y};
}
```

and in `main`, you could do:

```
auto [x, y] = mypoint.point_display();
cout << "The position of the point is ("
     << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
```

However, since the data members are public, you could just destructure the object and print out the values in `main`:

```
auto [x, y, radius] = mypoint;
cout << "The position of the point is ("
     << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual solution to this is to provide an overload of `operator <<` for class `MyPoint` to print the point.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyPoint{
    public:
        int x,y,radius;

        MyPoint()
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }

        MyPoint(int x1,int y1)
        {
            x=x1;
            y=y1;
        }

        int getAdd()
        {
            return x+y;
        }

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MyPoint& p);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const MyPoint& p)
{
    os << p.x << ", " << p.y;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    MyPoint mypoint { 1,2 };
    cout<<"The position of the point is "<<mypoint<<endl;
    cout<<"The sum of the coordinates is "<<mypoint.getAdd()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The position of the point is 1, 2
The sum of the coordinates is 3
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MgesZPwSDmn3S9cS)

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is *print* the coordinates, you could have the method do it:

```
void point_display()
{
  cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
}

...

cout<<"The position of the point is ";
mypoint.point_display();
cout << endl;
```

If you really want to *return* the coordinates, you could have separate accessors ("getters"):

```
int getX()
{
  return x;
}

int getY()
{
  return y;
}
```

or use references:

```
void getCoordinates(int &rx, int &ry)
{
  rx = x;
  ry = y;
}

...

int a, b;
mypoint.getCoordinates(a, b);
cout << a << " " << b << endl;
```

Comment: Your `point_display()` solution assumes that the output is `cout`, so if I do `myStream<<mypoint.point_display()<<endl;` the point will still be sent to `cout` instead of to `myStream`. That's not as satisfying as an override of `<<`.

Comment: @Caleb: It is not as general, but it is a lot simpler, and OP is a beginner who specifically asked for a way to **print** the coordinates, using **`cout`.** And yes, a competent programmer can adapt the function to take an `ostream` argument (which is not quite the same thing as overriding `<<`).